# How to use closure to capture the invocation by specific type and ignore others?

Tags: groovy, closures, spock

I have a mock with a method that can accept all children of an abstract type.In a test,this method may be invoked by different children multiple times,and I want to check that it is invoked by specific type once like this:

```
1*mockObject.method(_) {SpecificType ct->
     //check the ct's field value
}
```

the problem is that the closure always capture the first invocation due to:

```
mockObjectt.method(_)
```

can't distinguish different children types,so it match all invocations,then I tried another way like this:

```
 1*mockObject.method({it instanceof SpecificType}) {SpecificType ct->
     //check the ct's field value
}
```

but the problem of this way is that:

```
 {SpecificType ct->
     //Here,any check will return true,
     //I think the checkings in here are ignored
 }
```

is ignored always(I think I misused the groovy's closure here)

So question is:

```
 Is there elegant way to capture the invocation by specific child type with specific values and ignore others?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about: `1*mockObject.method({it instanceof SpecificType && it.field == fieldValue })` ?

Comment: Either that, or `1 * mockObject.method(_ as SpecificType) >> { assert it[0].field == fieldValue }`.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this sample code:

```
import spock.lang.Specification

class SimpleTestSpec extends Specification {

    private static class A { }

    private static class B extends A { }

    private static class C extends B { }

    private static class D extends A { }

    private static class TestClass {
        String foo(A value) {
            return "A: ${value}"
        }

        String foo(B value) {
            return "B: ${value}"
        }

        String foo(C value) {
            return "C: ${value}"
        }

        String foo(D value) {
            return "D: ${value}"
        }
    }

    private static class ComponentClass {
        private final TestClass testClass

        ComponentClass(TestClass testClass) {
            this.testClass = testClass
        }

        String foo(A value) {
            return testClass.foo(value)
        }
    }

    TestClass testClassMock = Mock(TestClass)

    ComponentClass componentClass = new ComponentClass(testClassMock)

    def setup() {
        testClassMock.foo(_ as D) >> "DDD"
        testClassMock.foo(_ as C) >> "CCC"
        testClassMock.foo(_ as B) >> "BBB"
        testClassMock.foo(_ as A) >> "AAA"
    }

    def "should use mocked DDD result"() {
        when:
        String result = testClassMock.foo(new D())

        then:
        result == "DDD"
    }

    def "should use mocked CCC result"() {
        when:
        String result = testClassMock.foo(new C())

        then:
        result == "CCC"
    }

    def "should use mocked BBB result"() {
        when:
        String result = testClassMock.foo(new B())

        then:
        result == "BBB"
    }

    def "should use mocked AAA result"() {
        when:
        String result = testClassMock.foo(new A())

        then:
        result == "AAA"
    }

    def "should record invocation based on dynamic type"() {
        when:
        componentClass.foo(new C())

        then:
        1 * testClassMock.foo(_ as C)
    }

    def "should return result associated with mocked invocation in runtime"() {
        when:
        String result = componentClass.foo(new D())

        then:
        result == "DDD"
    }
}
```

Gist file: https://gist.github.com/wololock/c59151b67d4c9b0c0c8e

You can specify expected type of an argument using `as` casting operator. But there is one tricky part - you need to stub class behavior in particular order: from most specific to most general. Try to mix the order in `setup()` and then you will see that tests will start failing.

You can also make use of Groovy's dynamic method invocation - notice how `ComponentClass` behaves with injectest `TestClass` instance which was previously stubbed with expected behavior. You can also count the number of invocations associated with specific type even if external call was made through the most general type method.

I hope it will help you resolve your problem. Best!